# MVC Tracing for specific requests only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to enable tracing in mvc, and specifically, I want to show tracing on a page if a certain condition is met.

Is it possible to enable `System.Diagnostics.Trace` writes to be displayed iff I request them in the context of a single request?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the [`Trace` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) doesn't have a way to turn tracing on/off depending on conditions you want to resolve on a per-request basis.  It's an all-or-nothing approach.

That said, I *highly* recommend the [MVC MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) (used here on the Stack Exchange sites, most notably to the public on the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)).

You basically get a rendering on your page like this:

[image: MiniProfiler screenshot]

And you can set the profiling on a per-request basis:

```
using StackExchange.Profiling;
...    
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.IsLocal)
    {
        MiniProfiler.Start();
    } 
}
```

The syntax is slightly different than using the `Trace` class, in that you have to use `using` statements, like so:

```
using (profiler.Step("Set page title"))
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
```

The reason being that this is a fundamentally different operation; when you trace, you are writing a piece of information out at a certain point in time.  When profiling, you are looking at segments of time, and the `using` statement allows one to scope those segments.

It might be a little overkill, but I'd gladly use this over `Trace` because of the profiling aspect as well as the non-intrusive nature of the information displayed (`Trace` has a nasty habit of making the page look very strange).

Answer (score 0):

I eventually resorted to passing a logger through my classes, and then conditionally displaying that information in the controller where necessary.

Using a container, I bound my logger instance to the scope of the HttpContext, and then just pumped it into my view model.